# Sonar starts w/o errors, but I can't access it via web browser

Tags: amazon-ec2, sonarqube

I've installed Sonar on an Ubuntu host using 'apt-get install sonar'. Since this is just a demo instance of Sonar for me to play with, I'm using the embedded H2 database.

Sonar seems to start up fine, and I don't have any errors or warnings in my sonar.log. However, when I try to hit it through my web browser, I get the ol' "Oops! Google Chrome could not connect to... blahblahblah".

The host is actually an EC2 instance - not sure if that makes a difference. It has the private IP assigned by Amazon, a URL (ie, ec2-xx-xx...amazonaws.com), and a vanity URL so I don't have to remember that monstrous underlying URL.

Right now, Sonar's properties looks like this. (I've intentionally X'd out the IP address where-ever it appears.)

```
sonar.web.host:                           10.xxx.xx.xxx
sonar.web.port:                           9000
sonar.web.context:                        /
...
sonar.jdbc.url:                            jdbc:h2:tcp://10.xxx.xx.xxx:9092/sonar
sonar.jdbc.driverClassName:                org.h2.Driver
sonar.embeddedDatabase.port:               9092
```

And I'm unable to access it by pointing my browser to ${monstrous_URL}:9000 or ${vanity URL}:9000.  I've also tried setting sonar.web.host to 0.0.0.0, and to ${monstrous_URL} - both to no avail, sadly.

For reference, this is what my sonar.log looks like:

```
STATUS | wrapper  | 2013/03/13 20:21:42 | --> Wrapper Started as Daemon
STATUS | wrapper  | 2013/03/13 20:21:43 | Launching a JVM...
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/03/13 20:21:43 | Wrapper (Version 3.2.3) http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.org
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/03/13 20:21:43 |   Copyright 1999-2006 Tanuki Software, Inc.  All Rights Reserved.
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/03/13 20:21:43 |
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/03/13 20:21:43 | 2013-03-13 20:21:43.422:INFO::Logging to org.sonar.application.FilteredLogger@7dc6a657 via org.sonar.application.FilteredLogger
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/03/13 20:21:43 | 2013-03-13 20:21:43.484:INFO::jetty-6.1.25
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/03/13 20:21:43 | 2013-03-13 20:21:43.756:INFO::NO JSP Support for /, did not find org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet
2013.03.13 20:21:44 INFO  o.s.s.p.ServerImpl  Sonar Server / 3.4.1 / 2f6a7f38e57ec8e9a7bedc81b3260ae735d2a8c8
2013.03.13 20:21:45 INFO  o.s.s.d.EmbeddedDatabase  Starting embedded database on port 9092 with url jdbc:h2:tcp://10.xxx.xx.xxx:9092/sonar
2013.03.13 20:21:45 INFO  o.s.s.d.EmbeddedDatabase  Embedded database started. Data stored in: /opt/sonar/data
2013.03.13 20:21:45 WARN  o.s.c.p.DefaultDatabase  H2 database should be used for evaluation purpose only
2013.03.13 20:21:45 INFO  o.s.c.p.Database  Create JDBC datasource for jdbc:h2:tcp://10.xxx.xx.xxx:9092/sonar
2013.03.13 20:21:47 INFO  o.s.s.p.DefaultServerFileSystem  Sonar home: /opt/sonar
2013.03.13 20:21:47 INFO  o.s.s.p.DefaultServerFileSystem  Deploy dir: /opt/sonar/war/sonar-server/deploy
2013.03.13 20:21:47 INFO  org.sonar.INFO  Install plugins...
2013.03.13 20:21:47 INFO  o.s.s.p.PluginDeployer  Deploy plugin Findbugs / 1.1 / 4785d335df6bd0e662d636a6fb03d79fbdda8c5a
2013.03.13 20:21:47 INFO  o.s.s.p.PluginDeployer  Deploy plugin JaCoCo / 1.1 / 4785d335df6bd0e662d636a6fb03d79fbdda8c5a
```

Does anyone have experience running Sonar on an EC2 instance, or have any tips for me? I'm stumped!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> And I'm unable to access it by pointing my browser to ${monstrous_URL}:9000 or ${vanity URL}:9000.

Change the security group attached to the EC2 instance to allow incoming connections to TCP port 9000.

Comment: OMG **smacks forehead**  That did it!  Thank you, interwebz and jamieb... I love you both.

Answer (score 1):

change H2 database to mysql with following enteries as 
sonar.

```
jdbc.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/sonar?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf8&rewriteBatchedStatements=true&useConfigs=maxPerformance
sonar.jdbc.driverClassName= com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
sonar.jdbc.validationQuery= select 1
```

and also  make following changes in sonar.properties :

```
sonar.web.host:                           0.0.0.0
sonar.web.context:                        /sonar
```